# Spark join - match any column from a long list

Tags: join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to join two tables, condition is one column of a table match any column form a very long list, i.e., the following:

```
columns = ['name001', 'name002', ..., 'name298']

df = df1.join(df2, (df1['name']==df2['name1']) | (df1['name']==df2['name2']) | ... | df1['name']==df2['name298'])
```

How can I implement this join in Pyspark, without writing the long conditions? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use loop over the `columns` list to build a `join` expression:

```python
join_expr = (df1["name"] == df2[columns[0]])
for c in columns[1:]:
    join_expr = join_expr | (df1["name"] == df2[c])
```

Or using `functools.reduce`:

```python
from functools import reduce

join_expr = reduce(
    lambda e, c: e | (df1["name"]==df2[c]),
    columns[1:], 
    df1["name"]==df2[columns[0]]
)
```

Now use `join_expr` to join:

```python
df = df1.join(df2, on=join_expr)
```